# Como pegar valores de um JSON e passar como variáveis SASS com Grunt

Tags: json, compilação, grunt, sass, task

Estou precisando compilar templates usando grunt e quero colocar as configurações de cores dentro de um arquivo JSON que estará dentro de cada pasta de layout, ou seja, preciso usar o Grunt para ler o JSON e passar os valores como variáveis para compilar o SASS.

Comment: Por que não usa essas variáveis diretamente nos arquivos SASS?

Answer (score 0):

Há esse plugin para Grunt https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-json-to-sass

**Instalação**

```
npm install grunt-json-to-sass --save-dev
```

**Configuração**

```
grunt.initConfig({
  json_to_sass: {
    your_target: {
      files: [
        {
          src: [
            'example.json'
          ],
          dest: '_example.scss'
        }
      ]
    },
  },
});
```

Espero que ajude!